# Black Screen with LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

i want to try LWJGL. I used the Tutorials form LWJGL-Wiki, but my Code still produces a black screen.

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

public class SimpleOGLRenderer {

public void start() {

    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
        Display.setTitle("Sandbox");
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0f, 800f, 600f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex2i(400, 400);
            glVertex2i(500, 400);
            glVertex2i(500, 500);
            glVertex2i(400, 500);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex2i(100, 100);
            glVertex2i(200, 200);               
        glEnd();

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }

    Display.destroy();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleOGLRenderer s = new SimpleOGLRenderer();
    s.start();
}

}
```

The Debugger in the Run-Settings

```
 -Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true
```

shows

```
 [LWJGL] Initial mode: 1920 x 1200 x 32 @60Hz
 [LWJGL] MemoryUtil Accessor: AccessorUnsafe
```

I have no idea what's wrong and all hints with changing color ([LWJGL - Black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702304/lwjgl-black-screen)) clear Screen ([LWJGL OpenGL Black Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367803/lwjgl-opengl-black-screen)) are not working.

I use a a Dell Insipron 1720 with a GeForece 8600M GT, Windows 7, 64-bit and DirectX v11.

Could you find my bug?

Comment: You never changed the color? Does doing something like `glColor3f(1, 0, 0);` change anything?

Comment: No, sorry. I tried before drawing and after clear, but nothing is happening. I also tried clearColor.

Comment: I found my mistake. One of my Settings in Eclipse was wrong. Now everything works fine. The Code is correct.

Comment: For other people's reference, would you mind listing what setting you had wrong?

Comment: ya i'd like to know how you fixed it >.>